# Rails, PgBouncer and DigitalOcean — how to work with Databases Connection Pools?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, digital-ocean, pgbouncer

Recently in DigitalOcean has the opportunity to create Databases. This is something like a turnkey solution based on the usual Droplet with a bunch of additional database features.

One of these additional features — Connection Pools. As far as I understand this is a PgBouncer.

If I connect the database to the Rails 5.2 application in the usual way (directly), then everything is fine.

But if I use the connection through the "Connection Pools", I will get an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicatePstatement: ERROR: prepared statement "a1" already exists

This will occur when any data is received from the database.

Tell me, please, how to make it all work?

Answer (score 17):

Set `prepared_statements` and `advisory_locks` to `false` in the database configurations.

More info [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database).

Comment: Thank you! This should be more obvious on DO website

Comment: Saved me. Not sure why DO doesn't mention this.